# Cross-orgin doesn't work with Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I have built a simple application with spring boot and front-end with angular5 , I enabled cross-origin for the Controller  without spring-security the app works well but when i just but the dependancies of spring-security cross-origin doesn't work, so what i have to do ?

Controller

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping(ResourceConstants.Product_URL)
   @Api(description = "Porduct and Categories resources")
   @CrossOrigin
   public class ProductResources {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo cateRepo;



    // Categories Resources
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/AllCategories")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Return All Categories")
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {

        return cateRepo.findAll();// .stream().
        // filter((c)->c.getActive()==1)
        // .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }}
```

my angular 5 code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../services/category.service';


import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  providers: [CategoryService]
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  currency = [];
  languages = [];
  links = [];
  constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.currency = ['USD', 'Egp'];
    this.languages = [
      'Arabic',
      'English'
    ];
    this.links = ['SignUp', 'Profile', 'Settings', 'SignIn'];

  }

  ngOnInit() {

console.log("Welcome");
    this.getAll()
            .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            err => {
                // Log errors if any
                console.log(err);
            });
  }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {


    //noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
    return this.http
        .get('http://localhost:8080/rest/api/product/AllCategories')
        .map(this.mapRoom);
}

mapRoom(response: Response): any[] {
    return response.json().content;
}


}
```

when run angular 5 on google chrome  i had this error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/rest/api/product/AllCategories 401 ()

 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/rest/api/product/AllCategories: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

what i should add?

Comment: How are you serving your Angular 5 app ? You need CORS for the Angular 5 to allow localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had it working prior to adding spring-security, I will assume that you already have proxy setup in Angular 5 in order to access the backend(since they are on different port).

In order to get CORS working with spring security you need to configure a CorsConfigurationSource bean this way:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

that's just the basic configuration you can also be more specific in allowed method/origin by using the methods :  setAllowedOrigins and setAllowedMethods from the CorsConfiguration class.

spring documentation regarding this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html